# React Native: Why isn't useEffect() getting called here?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

In my React Native app, I want to pass a function from `A` to `B` to update a prop in `A`. What ideally would happen is that `B` calls this function `updateProp1(true)`, and in response `A` logs `setting prop1 to true` and then logs `true` again from the `useEffect` function. What happens instead is it just logs `setting prop1 to true` but `useEffect` in `A` is *not* called. Can anyone explain why this is and how to call `useEffect` in `A`?

```
const A = (props) => {
  const [prop1, setProp1] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(prop1);
  }, [prop1])

  updateProp1 = (_prop1) => {
    console.log("setting prop1 to: ", _prop1);
    setProp1(_prop1);
  }

  return (
    <B updateProp1={updateProp1}/>
  )
}

const B = (props) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => props.updateProp1(true)}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: I don't know if it can resolve your problem but have you tried to replace updateProp1 = ... by const updateProp1 = ...

Comment: I will assume you simplified your code here? I copied and pasted this example in a CodeSand box and this works fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/useeffectpropchange-vlygx4. If you can get a sandbox to reproduce your bug I can help.